# How to close confirm window dynamically without passing arguments for cancel

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am calling confirm(message) function of javascript for onclick of "JOIN CHAT" button of a queued chat conversation .

If the condition is true it will perform some action else its false it wont perform the intended action.

```
ChatClient.prototype.JoinChat = function(chatid) {
  var msg = (this.CanPickup(chatid)) ? "Pickup this chat?" : "Join this chat?";
  if (confirm(msg)) {
    var myKey = this.MyInfo.id;
    if(isAdmin && _self.view == 1 && chat.adminOwner != window.myUserKey){
    this.AddUserToChat(chatid, myKey); 
    confirm = function() { return false; };
    }      
    {
    $('.Chat').removeClass('Selected');
    }    

    // no need to Select chat, the join message will open it afterwards, and avoids opening the chat too early
  }
};
```

Now my problem is multiple users logged into different sessions.
If the first user clicks  "JOIN CHAT" button and the second user also clicks same  "JOIN CHAT" button of a queued chat conversation both will get confirm message pop up with OK and Cancel buttons.

If the first user clicks ok, he joins the conversation but the second user still have the pop-up in his view.

Is there a solution to close the confirm popup for rest of the users without having to click cancel if first user have already clicked OK.

I have tried closing confirm for rest of the users using this code. It doesn't work though.

confirm = function() { return false; };

Comment: Hi, I for one might need to see a bit more code for clarity on what's going on here, thanks.

Comment: When an user clicks on OK, you can send an AJAX request to the server. Have each client poll the server to check if anyone has clicked OK. If yes, close the popup. Not familiar with WebSocket, but if using WebSocket, I think another option would be to have the server push out a notification to each client when it detects that "OK" has been clicked. Each client would then close the popup.

Comment: I have tried to push out a message that the chat is already picked up but it works only on clicking cancel button of popup. without closing it that message is not displaying as the popup is expecting an argument for boolean yes or no

Comment: Don't use the built-in confirm popup. I believe that one is blocking, so you won't be able to run any code until the popup is dismissed by the user. Instead, create a custom popup.

Comment: Okey. Will try and update. Thank you